# ping: unknown host with iptables enabled

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, dns, ping

I can't ping www.google.com. However I can ping the IP address:

```
ping 74.125.237.142
```

At first, I thought it is a problem with my DNS settings. But I checked my `resolv.conf`, `hosts`, and `hostname` carefully. They are all correct.

When I clear all firewall rules using:

```
iptables -F
```

Then `ping www.google.com` works

So the problem is still with the firewall or NAT settings.

Can someone  provide some ideas? How can I set the `iptables` rules?

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   13  1476 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    80 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   34  6030 INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   34  6030 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   34  6030 INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 17 packets, 2694 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   82  9498 OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  A      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  p2p1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      A       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      p2p1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (3 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_external (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_external_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_external_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_external_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_external_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_external_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_external_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (3 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 IN_public  all  --  A      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   16  3011 IN_public  all  --  p2p1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   18  3019 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_dmz (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 IN_dmz_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_dmz_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_dmz_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_dmz_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_dmz_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_dmz_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_external (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 IN_external_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_external_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_external_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_external_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_external_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_external_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_home (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 IN_home_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_home_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_home_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_home_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:631 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_home_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_home_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_internal (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 IN_internal_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_internal_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_internal_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_internal_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:631 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_internal_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_internal_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (3 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   34  6030 IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   34  6030 IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   34  6030 IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
   34  6030 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_work (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 IN_work_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_work_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_work_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_work_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:631 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_work_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_work_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: It would help if you provided your current iptables rules. `iptables -nvL`

Comment: It seems Port 53 is filtered incorrectly.

Comment: iptables rules are provided

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a rule to allow UDP port 53. Without UDP port 53, you don't get DNS, so it's not surprising that name resolution fails.

You need to add a rule to allow incoming UDP traffic from port 53, at least from the DNS server(s) of your Internet access providers. Something like

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

possibly with additional restrictions, possibly in a different rule (I don't understand your firewall's organization). Since your firewall rules seem to have been automatically generated, you'll probably want to change the settings of your firewall configuration tool rather than calling `iptables` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the previous answer, try to add a rule that allow traffic UDP like the previous answer, and TCP connection like this:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

TCP connection is used when the response data size exceeds 512 bytes, that is normal.

Comment: Thanks. And will these two command accept all process to connect port 53 ?

Comment: Those commands will accept all traffic from any hosts to this machine on port 53 TCP and UDP.

Comment: If you need to accept all traffic to with destiny to other DNS, use: "iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT" and "iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT"